# Mudhal Alwargal

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, alwar

In the Vaishnava Tradition Poigai, Bootham and Pey Alwars are called Mudhal Alwargal. What is the background of this and why not other 9 alwars are not called mudhal alwars?Further which amsa of Lord Vishnu these Mudal alwars emanated?

Answer needed from suitable Hindu related purana ithihasas.

Comment: They are called Mudal Azhvars, because they were the **first** azhvars on earth, and were born at nearly the same time.

Comment: citing from grandhas or divaya prabandhas or srimad bagavatham or related purana needed. This is not the exact answer.

Comment: Since I could not post the references at the moment I posted a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: You take time and post with suitable references. Anybody knows the answer given by you as the question consist Mudal Alwargal